# .net activity using ondeamnd HDinsinght cluster for github sample CrossAppDomainDotNetActivity is error out

Tags: azure-data-factory

running .net activity CrossAppDomainDotNetActivity from below url
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/tree/master/Samples
it's error out and give error

Invalid .Net activity package found in blob. Ensure that the package files are in the root of the zip file. Assembly Name: CrossAppDomainDotNetActivitySample.dll. Job Name: 9af46300-0ca6-4b61-91e8-a0598e6a8649. Package File: MyDotNetActivity.zip. Error message: Could not load file or assembly 'CrossAppDomainDotNetActivitySample' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

Comment: Did you follow [the instructions](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/tree/master/Samples/CrossAppDomainDotNetActivitySample)?

Comment: Yes,i follow the instructions.